# Android EditText Set Max Length

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I was trying to set the max length of an EditText, but I didn't get success.

I tried like this:

```
a.setFilters (new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter (a.Length) });
```

and I get some errors ( Not at a.Length ).

and like this:

```
a.setMaxLength ( a.Lenght);
```

and still some errors.

I think that I forget some headers but that's just a guess.

Metion that I use Xamarin. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Manwal My primary error is 'Android.Widget.EditText' does not contain a definition for 'setMaxLength/setFilters' and no extension method 'setMaxLength/setFilters' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Widget.EditText' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Answer (score 19):

If you using c# best if you try it like this

```
MyEditText.SetFilters( new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(10) } );
```

Comment: I dont know why this has down votes because this works, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
TextView a = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] filter = new InputFilter[1];
filter[1] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
a.setFilters (filter);
```

or Use this in your xml:

```
android:maxLength="20"
```

Comment: Didn't work ... And I don't need in XML. The sequence being in a conditional structure (if).

Answer (score 0):

> editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(12) });

OR

> EditText youredittext = new EditText(this);
>
> int maxLength = 10;
>
> InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
>
> fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
>
> youredittext.setFilters(fArray);

Comment: I don't need in XMI. The sequence being in a conditional structure (if). And programmatically I specified in description that didn't work like this.

Comment: can you put your error log ? so that we can able to actual problem.. as such this method is works for me so that am asking to put your error log

Comment: 'Android.Widget.EditText' does not contain a definition for 'setMaxLength/setFilters' and no extension method 'setMaxLength/setFilters' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Widget.EditText' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Mention again that I use Xamarin.

Comment: I have change in answer , please check will it be work or not ?

Comment: if answer will helps you then let me know please

Comment: I stuck at InputFilter ( row 3 )

Comment: Are you sure that isn't possible to be caused by headers ?