# Error using EditText setMaxLength

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a little problem. I was trying to set the max length of an EditText, but I didn't get success.

I tried like this:

```
a.setFilters (new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter (a.Length) });
```

and I get some errors ( Not at a.Length ).

and like this:

```
a.setMaxLength ( a.Lenght);
```

and still some errors.

I think that I forget some headers but that's just a guess.

(I don't need in XML)

The primary error is 'Android.Widget.EditText' does not contain a definition for 'setMaxLength/setFilters' and no extension method 'setMaxLength/setFilters' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Widget.EditText' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Metion that I use Xamarin. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android EditText Set Max Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424646/android-edittext-set-max-length)

Comment: @Cheesebaron Is a duplicate because no one success to help me to solve this problem.

Comment: That is no reason to create a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even explore which methods and properties are ***ACTUALLY*** available to you on the instance of `EditText`?

Method names in C# are generally start with a capital letter so simply fixing that and actually using a filter that **exists** helps a lot.

```
editText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new InputFilterLengthFilter(10) });
```

That for instance compiles just fine...

Next time please explore the available values and methods through the intellisense available to you in the IDE, it can actually be useful. Just blindly copying some Java code into your app will rarely work.

Comment: Seriously, you can't even see past a spelling mistake?

Comment: Whatever ... I already mentioned in description that this method don't work.

Comment: I have tested this, it works. The answer has been edited to be the correct code.

Comment: Finally I've done solve my problem , the problem was that I needed the namespace Android.Text , how I mentioned in description. Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Xamarin Studio which I see you are using in the image you posted fixes this for you if you use it correctly.